# How do I know what the latest version of Rhythmbox is?

Tags: rhythmbox

A few questions guys, would really be glad if you could help.

How do I know what the latest version of Rhythmbox is (is there a rhythmbox official repository?)? And say I dont have the latest version of Ubuntu (I'm using 10.04, personally my favourite ubuntu release yet, especially since i'm not a big fan of unity), can I upgrade Rhythmbox to the leatest version? If so how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should you update?? The new versions do no visualizers.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx, I've found only the [WebUpd8 Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/rhythmbox?field.series_filter=lucid), which contains the backports for Rhythmbox and it will update RB to the 0.13.1 version, which is 3 versions before the current stable (2.95). 
Here is how to update using this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/rhythmbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To know which version of RB you are using, you can use [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/synaptic/)
and filter by Rhythmbox or going to Rhythmbox menu, under Help to see if the version is specified.

To know which is the latest version of Rhythmbox, you can go to their [official site](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/).

Comment: Basically `rhythmbox 2.95` which is the latest rhythmbox is ported to gtk3 so it may not work on lucid. http://webupd8.org/2012/01/rhythmbox-finally-ported-to-gtk3.html

Comment: Yes, I think so, because Rhythmbox is Gnome official media player and they have ported it to Gtk+ 3 for compatibility with Gnome 3.

Comment: Is there a way to check the latest version of Rhythmbox for Ubuntu 22.04?